# How to find possible config settings for UI Components

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

For the UI components, I see nodes for data/config and data/js_config. It seems like a lot of components have this option. How do I find the possible values available to be set for each component? Is there any type of guide?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At top of the page, you can see something like this

`<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">`

You can see the configuration (**Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd**) of that file in

> magento/module-ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd

Answer (score 0):

The nodes `data/config` and `data/js_config` are used in `\Magento\Ui\Component\AbstractComponent::prepare()`.

Unfortunately there aren't detailed guides, i advise you to start from here with xdebug and discover how they are used to create the json to configure the ui component js, in your case `Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group` (`vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/components/group.js`).

The params passed through the configuration are used in js file and its ancestor.